# How to visit ssl enabled development website when using hostfile

Tags: google-chrome, dns, ssl, hosts-file, web-development

Pre "ssl required" on domains, to visit a development site on a development computer (Windows), I edit my host file and point the domain to the development server IP address. Which was working flawlessly.

Now that all domains are required by most browser to be ssl, is there a similar way to visit a development page on my computer?

Hostfile is still working but google chrome won't allow the connection anymore. I am getting this error.

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from yourdomain.app (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

yourdomain.app normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to yourdomain.app this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be yourdomain.app, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.

You cannot visit yourdomain.app right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.
```

Any suggestion how can I proceed with development the old way? I do not want to put it in other subdomain or folder because I have to change these references when going live. Unlike the hostfile method, everything is as it is.

Thanks

Comment: The `host` file simply provides name resolution.  That's worked because you've had a response from the website.  The fact that it's not the expected response is not a name resolution problem, but more likely a TLS configuration problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Any suggestion?

Comment: Even though browsers give you a warning with http, it does not mean https is required. But https combined with HSTS and a wrong certificate can not work - so after disabling HSTS on the web server you also need to [remove the site's cached certificate in your browser](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/security/how-to-disable-hsts).

Comment: @Furty, removing HSTS? is this something I need to ask my host?

Comment: Yes as you said you are the developer, one would assume you have control over the web server